# System.OutOfMemoryException in reportviewer winform - an error occurred during local report processing

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, report, rdlc

I used a winform with ReportViewer control. When data is being loaded to report, its showing error :

> An Error Occured during local report processing.
>   An unexpected error occurred in Report Processing.
>   Exception of type System.OutOfMemoryException

[System.OutOfMemoryException details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/slR2T.png)

I used this code in form load event :

```
ReportViewr1.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Local
Dim ReportDataSource2 As New Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportDataSource
ReportDataSource2.Name = RPSet.DataSetName
ReportDataSource2.Value = ds.Tables(0)
ReportViewr1.LocalReport.ReportPath = "C:\Reports\Report1.rdlc"
ReportViewr1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(ReportDataSource2)
ReportViewr1.RefreshReport()
```

where *ds* is my dataset.
My system configuration is : 
Windows 8.1 64 bit (genuine) 
Core i7 processor 
8 GB of DDR3 ram (1600 FSB) 
2 GB DDR5 Graphic Card 
500 GB SSD

I found my program memory consumtion is 300 to 400 MB only. 
Then why it is out of memory ?
[Only 322 MB consumed by program while processing - details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0wbPk.png)

Comment: what's in the `ds`?

Comment: It contains a select command with filters for billing details. It returns about 1000 rows.

Comment: My system have 8 GB ram and 64 bit. The program is consuming only 322 MB, Is there any way to increase the memory limit of the program, to avoid outofmemory exception ?

Comment: No, there is no way to increase the memory limit. Before .NET framework 4.5 you could use up to 2 GB of memory anyway and higher allows more than 2GB. Run the  `Debug > Show Diagnostic Tools` and try to work out from there how much memory is actually being used, when the GC gets called etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried the properties of Tablix or Rectangle in rdlc. It contains an option like

> keep contents together on a single page, if possible

It can be Unchecked. It will try to load the contents of the pages in the same page or single page. Which sometimes consumes more memory.

[image: Uncheck the option]